# How to make Spring Boot skipping some configurations

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, spring-profiles

I have a Spring-Boot project which works with DB-connections and a lot of other stuff.
Now I added another "main-class" to the project. The thing is: by starting this class, all configuration settings (which come from application.yml) are loaded. But thats not what I want. 
I want the project to start without trying to bind to any datasource...
But how?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add several main classes? Try using different profiles instead. And you can start your application with the -Dspring.profiles.active=? property.

Example:
Just add a application-test.properties and run your application with -Dspring-profiles.active=test and the properties in the test property file will be loaded. And potentially overwrite properties with the same key in application.properties.